# Deploying PHP Application to AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm getting error while deploying PHP Application where I've successfully uploaded application files. The error is pasted below, please suggest.

[Instance: {instance id} Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed .

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you haven't created database instance. you need to create database instance and it should be connected with AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Comment: Database is not obligatory. Not all applications use databases.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment. If so, try going into the AWS Management Console, pulling up your EC2 instances, and terminating the instance having issues.

Elastic Beanstalk's Auto Scaling rules will re-launch a new instance in its place, and re-run any tasks necessary for deployment.

If you're using `.ebextensions` for custom configuration, you may need to double-check your settings.